# How can I change the rowStyle in jsPDF?

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

### Issue Description

I want to change the text color of the non-alternative rows

### Code Sample

```js
autoTable(doc, {

    startY: 120,
    head: [["Descripción", "Valor", "Impuestos"]],
    body: tableData,
    theme: "striped",
    styles: { halign: "left",},
    columnStyles: {
      0: { cellWidth: 80, textColor: [255, 255, 255] },
      1: { textColor: [255, 255, 255] },
      2: { textColor: [255, 255, 255] },
    },
    headStyles: { fillColor: [0, 10, 104], textColor: [255, 255, 255] },
    alternateRowStyles: { fillColor: [35, 46, 149]},
    tableLineColor: [6, 23, 39],
    tableLineWidth: 0.1,
  });
```